# how to split the serial number in string array

Tags: c#

i have the following code in dictionary

```
SN00001002001
SN00001002002
SN00001002003
SN00001002004
 ...
AN00001002006
AN00001002007
AN00001002008.
```

I want to display it as

```
SN00001002 001-006  6(count)
AN00001002 001-008  8(count)
```

i used the following code

```
Dictionary<object, int> counts = new Dictionary<object, int>();

            foreach (string item in str1)
            { 
               if (!counts.ContainsKey(item1))
                    {
                        counts.Add(item1, 1);                           
                   }                    }
                else
                {
                    counts[item]++;                        
                }
            }
```

it displays the counts correctly as

```
SN00001002   6(count)
AN00001002   8(count)
```

, but not with the serial no. can any one suggest an idea for this.

Comment: Your code is syntactically incorrect. Also you might want to add the line where you output the counts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out...

```
var serialNumbers = from sn in str1 
        group sn by sn.Substring(0, 10) into g
        select new { 
                         Key = g.Key, 
                         Cnt = g.Count(), 
                         Min = g.Min(v => v.Substring(10)), 
                         Max = g.Max(v => v.Substring(10))
                     };

foreach (var sn in serialNumbers)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}-{2} {3}(count)", sn.Key, sn.Min, sn.Max, sn.Cnt);
}
```

Here is the code I used to test above (from LinqPad)

```
List<string> str1 = new List<string>();
str1.Add("SN00001002001");
str1.Add("SN00001002002");
str1.Add("SN00001002003");
str1.Add("SN00001002004");
str1.Add("SN00001002005");
str1.Add("SN00001002006");
str1.Add("AN00001002001");
str1.Add("AN00001002002");
str1.Add("AN00001002003");
str1.Add("AN00001002004");
str1.Add("AN00001002005");
str1.Add("AN00001002006");
str1.Add("AN00001002007");
str1.Add("AN00001002008");

var serialNumbers = from sn in str1 
    group sn by sn.Substring(0, 10) into g
    select new { Key = g.Key, Cnt = g.Count(), Min = g.Min(v => v.Substring(10)), Max = g.Max(v => v.Substring(10))};

foreach (var sn in serialNumbers)
{
    string serialNumber = string.Format("{0} {1}-{2} {3}(count)", sn.Key, sn.Min, sn.Max, sn.Cnt); 
    serialNumber.Dump();
}
```

Output is ...

```
SN00001002 001-006 6(count)
AN00001002 001-008 8(count)
```

Comment: hi, Gene S, its working well, thanks a lot... but small error for me is in Dump(). Can u explain this plz.

Comment: @chitra.  Dump is an extension used in LinqPad only.  If you do not have LinqPad then probably a console application with a Console.WriteLine would work better.